Android Chrome custom tab redirection not captured for some devices
Chrome custom tab intent is launched from fragment, and I am handling the redirection in RedirectHandlerActivity.
The issue is that for some devices (in this case Google Pixel 4 & Samsung A32) it works and successfully opens my redirection activity, But there are cases in which redirection is not handled and the Chrome tab stays open (tested on Pixel 7 & Samsung A33).
 val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
 val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
 customTabsIntent.intent.setData(Uri.parse(url))
 resultLauncher.launch(customTabsIntent.intent)

Manifest
<activity
        android:name=".RedirectHandlerActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/redirect/callback"
                android:scheme="https" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>

P.S
The domain is also trusted (by assetslinks.json) and still has an issue, another weird thing is that for some devices (tested it on 3 different pixels) it is not trusted on the first install and if I uninstall the app and reinstall it again then it appears trusted.
